# Understanding libc++ and libstdc++ packages on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, gcc, c++

When searching on `apt`, I noticed that there're lots of similar libstdc++ packages:

```
libc++-1
LLVM C++ Standard library

libc++-1-11
libc++-1-12
...
LLVM C++ Standard library

libc++-dev
LLVM C++ Standard library (development files)

libc++-11-dev
libc++-12-dev
...
LLVM C++ Standard library (development files)

==============================================

libstdc++5
The GNU Standard C++ Library v3

libstdc++6
GNU Standard C++ Library v3

libstdc++6-8-dbg
libstdc++6-9-dbg
...
GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debug build)

libstdc++-8-dev
libstdc++-9-dev
...
GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
```

I believe `libc++` is for `LLVM` and `libstdc++` is for `GCC`. `-dev` packages are header files for compiling and `non-dev` packages are shared libraries for running.

But what does these version number means? You have `libc++-1` and `libc++-1-x`, and `x` varies. `libstdc++` has similar naming convention and have a `-dbg` package. What does this `debug build` means?

On my machine (Ubuntu 20.04) only `libstdc++-9-dev` and `libstdc++6` is installed. When will I need `libc++-1`?